# Failed to install project.apk on device 'emulator-5554

Tags: android, android-emulator

It failed 3 times in a row! What can be the reason for that? I made significant changes to the project since the last run (which succeeded), so can it be something in my code that makes it crash?
Thanks.

Comment: Please post any relevant errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post any other errors that are relevant.

Here are some things to try:

Shut down and restart adb:

1. Open command prompt (Start > Run > cmd)
2. Type adb kill-server and then hit enter
3. Type adb devices and then hit enter

Clean and rebuild your project completely. If you are using Eclipse:

1. Click the Project menu at the top, go to Clean
2. Select your project, then click OK

I'm sure you have done this, but also try restarting your IDE.

This may sound stupid, but make sure your AVD IS running (and not locked up).